# Output formatting of system call

Tags: print, format

Playing around with some uuid generation code, I found this

```
(defun get-random-uuid ()
    (interactive)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (call-process "uuidgen" nil t nil)
      (buffer-substring-no-properties 1 (line-end-position 0))))
```

i.e.,

```
"732e8146-8fc3-4325-a99c-1699817790c7"
```

It works, but it outputs the uuid as a string. I just want it to be plain. This outputs without quotes, but seems to generate a number first, then the uuid

```
(defun new-insert-random-uuid ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "uuidgen" t))
```

i.e.,

```
ELISP> (new-insert-random-uuid)
201 (#o311, #xc9)
ELISP> b413aed2-0da3-45fd-95f8-699b94d152fb
```

How would I get it without quotes and without the initial number generated?

Comment: Define what you mean by *"output"*, and what you mean by *"I just want it to be plain."*.  You already had it in your temporary buffer in a "plain" form - no quotes. But of course `buffer-substring` returns that text as a string. Why kind of Lisp value do you want it as, if not a string?  If it didn't have hyphens you could get it as a hex number.  But just what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: What @Drew said.  Do you want the result as a *symbol*? If so, you can call `intern` on the string.

Comment: The first code block,`get-random-uuid` actually performs as I want it to when I call it "interactive," i.e., by calling it with `M-x get-random-uuid`. However, I'm confused as to why just a normal call (e.g., in *scratch*) as `(get-random-uuid)` produces the uuid string (without double quotes), but directly thereafter `nil`. Same with the second code example. Why are the interactive and regular uses of these functions producing different behaviors?